# Sharepoint 2010: Assign a user permissions to edit other users items without adding "Manage List" permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions

In our Sharepoint we have the need to assign permissions to a user so he can edit the entries created by other users, while the remaining users maintain their current permission to add/modify/delete only their own created entries. We don't want to give this user "Manage List" permissions, only the permission to modify entries from other users. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run an Impersonation Step and do the highlighted line below in a SharePoint Designer (SPD) 2010 workflow.
I created a custom permission that gave the users only create rights. Then assigned permissions based on some conditions.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the "add/modify/delete only their own created entries"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new permission level as a copy of Contribute and add the "Manage Permissions" permission only. I call this "Contribute and Permissions Mod". Then assign your user this new permission level on the list.